# JS and methods in class emulation

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I am new to this so I'll try to be as detailed as possible.

I am creating a JS class using functions.

```
function Bandstar(p, id)
{
  var numberOfSides, Xcenter, Ycenter;
  var canvas;
  var circlesInt;
  var linesInt;
  var lines;
  var linesInt2;
  var linesMidToEdge; 
.....
```

When it comes to methods, I just declare them like this:

```
this.IAset = function(a) 
{
   for (var i =0; i<= this.numberOfSides-1;i++)
   {
      if (parseInt(a[i]) == a[i])
         this.circles[i].value = a[i];
      else
         return false;
    }

    this.IArepaint();
    return true
}
```

and that's pretty much it.

The problem now is that, when I am creating a specific method:

```
this.moveFunc = function(e)
{
   var p = e.target;
   this.IAmove(p);
};
```

with the method `IAmove` being declared as follows:

```
this.IAmove = function(p)
{
   var m = (p.oTop - this.Ycenter ) / (p.oLeft - this.Xcenter);
   var linea = m * ( p.left - p.oLeft) + p.oTop;
   var ejeX = p.left;
   ...
}
```

The compiler just keeps throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e)   {     var p = e.target;     this.IAmove(p);   } has no method 'IAmove'
```

So, the thing is that I am declaring `moveFunc` as a function but then when I try to get to use `this` property, it doesn't actually use the instance of the class above it, (`Bandstar`), but of itself (and obviously `moveFunc` doesn't have a method called `IAmove`, the class on which it is being created is)...

I thought this was just like it worked, but I must not be getting the concept of heritage and class morphology in JS right.

How can I access a method in a class from another method inside that same class? If I just write `IAmove(p)` it will just say the method `IAmove()` is undefined (because it isn't, it's part of the Bandstar namespace.

I know it must be something stupid that I'm not seeing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context inside your function may change based on your call. So `this` could not be the original object.

You should add a private var like:

```
 function Bandstar(p, id)
{
  var numberOfSides, Xcenter, Ycenter;
  var canvas;
  var that = this; // add this line
```

and use it when you try to call function (or get properties) of original object

```
this.moveFunc = function(e)
  {
    var p = e.target;
    that.IAmove(p); // change this line
  };
```

for be sure to point to original object.

EDIT: According with comments you can read more infos in [Stuart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154625/js-and-methods-in-class-emulation/14154837#14154837)

Comment: ...the reason being that functions in js are objects, so that the value of this in a function is actually the function itself

Comment: I have to say that this simply false information. The `this` will only ever point to the actual function being called if you did `fn.fn = fn; fn.fn();` or `fn.bind(fn); fn();` otherwise it will be the object attached to the function when it was called or the global namespace `window`

Comment: stuart I don't understand your point. All I can say is that the trick up there worked. It seems to be that in js, when you create a function method inside another function, they are not herited by other functions created inside the method... so you can only access the variables that are not functions.... that's what I am understanding even though it might be wrong.

Comment: Its a shame that although the "trick" worked, nothing has been learnt and you have come away without the understanding the `this` scope or a richer understanding of object construction in JavaScript.

Comment: @StuartWakefield mmh.. this is not a false information. But incomplete. In the OP case the context change, without any other specification. If I understand your comment, you want extend the information in varous other cases?

Comment: Sorry I should have said that it was directed at didierc. Your solution glossed over the problem of understanding `this` which is a pretty important JavaScript construct or tackle the root cause which is losing the `this` context on an objects members, however, your approach is a valid approach.

Comment: I undestrstand your point of view, but the question was simply "How can I access a method in a class from another method inside that same class?"

Comment: And your answer is not necessary to access a method from another method as illustrated by this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2VfFr/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of those methods are defined in the constructor **the syntax is correct**. The following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VfFr/) illustrates it working, the code is based on a simplified version of your code...

```
function Test() {
    this.move = function(p) {
        document.write("Moved to: " + p);
    };
    this.another = function(e) {
        this.move(e.target);
    };
}

var test = new Test();
test.another({target: "The moon"});
```

The cause of the issues is likely to be one of <strike>two</strike> three things:

1. How the method `moveFunc` is called
2. When the method `moveFunc` is called
3. How the method `IAmove` is called (it may not be the `moveFunc` function that is causing that error).

The `this` keyword will reference the scope of the function which is typically the owner of the method...

```
var bandstar = new Bandstar(p, id);
bandstar.moveFunc(e); // this should be bandstar
```

The only reasons that might not be the case is if you are explicitly binding the `moveFunc` function to another object or a more common situation is that the function is being called without being attached to the owner...

```
var bandstar = new Bandstar(p, id);
var moveFunc = bandstar.moveFunc(e);
moveFunc(e); // this will now be window
```

The `this` keyword will default to `window` if the owner is detached from it. You can bind the function using.

```
var bandstar = new Bandstar(p, id);
var moveFunc = bandstar.moveFunc(e);
moveFunc.bind(bandstar);
moveFunc(e); // this will now be bandstar again
```

In the second issue both methods must be defined in the constructor before the `moveFunc` function can be called

```
this.moveFunc = function(e) { ... }
this.moveFunc(e); // Will throw an error that IAmove does not exist in the object
this.IAmove = function(p) { ... }
```

You can log the `this` object using `console.log(this);` to find out what it is.

It looks as though from your error that you are trying to call `IAmove` on the `moveFunc` function. For this error to be caused you would need to have called `moveFunc` with itself as the owner or the bound object... Which is not a particularly likely.

I have a hunch that the error may not actually be related to the `this.IAmove(p);` call in the `moveFunc` as assumed. **Post the stack trace** and we can use that to find where the error occurred.

Comment: I tried it the other way around but it didn't actually change anything. I mean, i declared IAmove first, then moveFunc and whenever I used the moveFunc it still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wants to add these methods to **your `Bandstar` prototype**.

```
function Bandstar(p, id)
{
   // ...
}

Bandstar.prototype.IAset = function(a) 
{
   // ...
}

Bandstar.prototype.moveFunc = function(e)
{
   var p = e.target;
   this.IAmove(p);
};
```

This way your methods keep the Bandstar context, and `this` will remain Bandstar instance reference.

Have a look at [**Object.prototype** reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: Using this will still give me the same error. I guess that is just because I am declaring the prototypes INSIDE the function rather than outside. However I needed them to be declared inside of the function and inside of the constructor, since I am using one of the functions before the thing is created.

Comment: @JuanVilar you also can use the `.call()` method to change the context of the function, in case you feel this is more appropriated. @Chumkiu answer is also a common trick to keep a reference of your instance.